# How to make a post request to a google cloud run service using python?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, curl, google-cloud-run

I can send the request by using this

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
```

However I cannot do it using python.
I have already successfully authenticated for other google services using service accounts, but authenticating correctly by including the token in the request seems to be impossible. I could not find any working example on the internet.
Do you have any working code for that?

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you're using, errors and so on. SO is not examples or tutorial site

Comment: You must put an identity token. Share you code, we can help to fix this

Comment: You need to create an OIDC identity token. How depends on what type of identity. Common principals are user and service accounts. Google has documentation and examples.

Comment: There are several answers on StackOverflow in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-platform%5D+python+identity+token

Comment: This example duplicates your gcloud command:  https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/1.14.0/reference/google.oauth2.id_token.html#google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token